# Get the number of submission on form submit

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps, google-forms

I am developing a Google Apps Script, which is bundled with a Google Form.
When a user submits a response, I need to send an email including the number of submission (i.e. that user is the n-th person to submit the form).

I didn't find a method in the API which can perform the same action. I came up with 2 workarounds but they don't work:

### 1. Check by Response ID

I tried to go through all form responses and check if this response's ID matches, then record the index.

```
function onFormSubmit(e)
{
  var formResponses = e.source.getResponses();

  for(var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++)
  {
    if(e.response.getId() == formResponses[i].getId())
    {
      Logger.log("Find it! Your number of submission is " + (i + 1));
      break;
    }
  }
  Logger.log("Cannot find response in form!");
}
```

However, I am surprized to find that `formResponses` does not include the response just submitted by the user (since I always get the `Cannot find response in form!` message). I guess Google insert this response to the form after executing this function.

### 2. Check by total number of form responses

Then I came up with another idea. Knowing that the response just submitted by the user is not included inside the form, why not just count the number of responses inside the form and add 1?

```
function onFormSubmit(e)
{
  var formResponses = e.source.getResponses();
  Logger.log("Your number of submission is" + (formResponses.length + 1));
}
```

The problem is, if more than 1 user submit the form at the same time, they may get the incorrect number. I guess the reason is that a user may get the number that is not updated as another user has already submitted the response which is not yet inserted to the form.

I would like to know if there is a proper way to do this. Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you consider to use a script bound to the linked spreadsheet instead of the form? You could use the row number minus one as the submission number.

Comment: The response ID in the event object may not be the response ID in the Form.  There are basically two response ID's for the same response.  I've run into issues with this myself.  You could try using Lock Service and test it to see if it deals with the issue of two or more users submitting the Form simultaneously, or in rapid succession.